# How to generate transfer code/script in WinSCP

Tags: sftp, winscp

I have the below command I started writing to copy a file from a local box to the remote directory. I am very new to this and confused by the documentation somewhat. Can I use the `"Your Command 1 and 2"` params at the end to do like `"c:\somefile.txt" "\in\"`?

I want to do this without PowerShell, or script. Just raw command line and no additional files to import in command line args. My goal is to set up a Windows Task Scheduler job and has it run this single command.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe /log="C:\writable\path\to\log\WinSCP.log" /ini=nul /command "open sftp://myusername@myftpsite.com/ -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 wbb2bQRmDJqkaLbuYKsnGdxQ40mIIedeXChRsAYC3ig="" -privatekey=""C:\Users\my.user\Documents\SSHPrivateKey.ppk""" "Your command 1" "Your command 2" "exit"`

I see some examples here… https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting

Can't find auto-generate code function in transfer settings for full script code...

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command to upload a file is [`put`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put). You can place it instead of the `"Your command 1" "Your command 2"` placeholders like this:

```
"C:\...\WinSCP.exe" ... /command "open ..." "put C:\local\file.zip /remote/" "exit"
```

---

[WinSCP GUI can generate](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) a complete command-line including the `put` command for you:

- Initiate a transfer in the GUI. You have to do it a way that pops up the [Transfer Options dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_copy). The dialog does not typically show for drag&drop transfers (unless you [opt for it in preferences](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_environment)). Instead, use the main menu or a file(s) context menu, a toolbar button or a keyboard shortcut.
- On the dialog, drop down the menu at the *Transfer Settings* button.
- Select the *Generate Code* command.
- [Generate Transfer Code Dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script) opens.
- On the Generate Transfer Code Dialog, select the *Command-line* format.